# Azure DevOps - Azure Spring Cloud Blue/Green deployment results in no production deployment

Tags: azure, azure-devops, devops, blue-green-deployment, azure-spring-cloud

I have a weird problem with an Azure Spring Cloud deployment via Azure DevOps and the [AzureSpringCloud@0](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/deploy/azure-spring-cloud?view=azure-devops) task.

I try to setup a blue/green deployment with this task. I have the stage *blue* and the stage *green*. If my Azure DevOps task deploys to *blue* everything seems to be normal in the Azure portal but if my task deploys to *green* there is no production deployment according to Azure.

**This is the output from the Azure DevOps task:**

> Setting active deployment on app my-project to blue

**This is the warning in the Azure Portal:**

> This app has no production deployment. You can set production
> deployment in Deployments panel.

And it looks like this:

[image: Azure Portal with two staging deployments]

With an Azure CLI command like this...

> az spring-cloud app deployment list ...

...I get a JSON with both deployments but both are not active.

```
[
  {
    "id": "/.../deployments/blue",
    "name": "blue",
    "properties": {
      "active": false,
      "status": "Running"
    }
  },
  {
    "id": "/.../deployments/green",
    "name": "green",
    "properties": {
      "active": false,
      "status": "Running"
    }
  }
]
```

This is how I setup the task in Azure DevOps:

```
- task: AzureSpringCloud@0
  inputs:
    azureSubscription: 'My-Subscription'
    Action: 'Deploy'
    AzureSpringCloud: my-spring-cloud
    AppName: my-project
    UseStagingDeployment: true
    Package: $(Pipeline.Workspace)/my-java-app.jar
    RuntimeVersion: Java_8

- task: AzureSpringCloud@0
  inputs:
    azureSubscription: 'My-Subscription'
    Action: 'Set Production'
    AzureSpringCloud: my-spring-cloud
    AppName: my-project
    UseStagingDeployment: true
```

If I navigate to my application URL the app is running but I'm not sure which stage. If I run the Azure DevOps pipeline again it knows that *green* is currently in production and switches to *blue* but I don't know from where it gets this information.

Is that a known issue or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

About this issue, I notcie that you have two staging deployments and the devops task only try to specify the deployment by argument `UseStagingDeployment: true`.
I think the task cannot specify the right staging deployment when the app has two staging deployments. So you'd better specify the deploymentName explicitly. e.g.

```
- task: AzureSpringCloud@0
  inputs:
    azureSubscription: 'My-Subscription'
    Action: 'Set Production'
    AzureSpringCloud: my-spring-cloud
    AppName: my-project
    DeploymentName: "blue"
```